# What's wrong with my try/catch code?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

```
var tryThis = false
try {
  if (tryThis = true) {
    console.log("Why does this get printed?")
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log("The error is", e)
}
```

There's something definitely wrong with my understanding of Javascript's try/catch statements. I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Setting the value of a variable to true is always true.  (`tryThis = true`) instead of (`tryThis === true`), or arguably `(true === tryThis)` or even just `(tryThis)`.  Voting to close as off-topic: typo

Comment: I do not understand your question. Your try catch syntax is OK. You never get to print "The error is", simply because there is no error thrown in your code.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Actually, assignment returns `undefined`, which is falsy, not `true`.

Comment: @MattMorgan Uh ... evaluate this in the console: `if (foo = true) { console.log("true") }`

Comment: My bad.  It returns `undefined` if you just do the assignment.

Comment: @MattMorgan assignment is an expression that always returns the value that was assigned - this is intentional behavior.  Assigning a value to a variable during declaration (i.e. `var variable = value`) is a statement and returns undefined

Comment: Always learn something new here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
 if (tryThis = true) {
```

*assigns* `true` to `tryThis`, which evaluates to (as @Tibrogargan commented above) to `true`.  Instead:

```
 if (tryThis === true) {
```

You want to compare the values.  Use `===`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is actually assigning `true` to `tryThis`
if (tryThis = true)
```

## This is just to help you understand how to compare boolean values

**When you need to make a comparison between boolean values, you don't need to do this: `tryThis === true` because it's unnecessary.**

```
var tryThis = false
try {
  if (tryThis === true) {
              ^
```

**Just use the boolean value as follow:**

```
var tryThis = false
try {
  if (tryThis) { // this is the same as tryThis === true or tryThis !== false
      ^
```

**If you want to compare a boolean value to false, don't do this:**

```
 tryThis === false
         ^
```

**Rather, use the negation operator, so, do the following:**

```
 !tryThis
 ^
```